# Application stopped on device(no terminal errors) - doesn't show ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I try to make a simple ListView in Android.

**activity_labas.xml:**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/title_home2"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**labas.java:**

```
package com.labas.holiday.labas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class labas extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private TextView mTextMessage2;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);


                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    mTextMessage2.setText(R.string.title_dashboard2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_labas);

        mTextMessage2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        Log.i("myTag2", "STARTINGBOOTOM");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(labas.this, ListViewLoader.class);
        //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
        labas.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        //setContentView(R.layout);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

**ListViewLoader**

```
package com.labas.holiday.labas;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ListViewLoader extends ListActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

    // This is the select criteria
    static final String SELECTION = "((" +
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("myTag", "STAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTT");
        // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

        // Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        root.addView(progressBar);

        // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
        String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.labas.holiday.labas">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".labas"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ListViewLoader" android:label="@string/title_activity_test"/>
        <activity android:name="Testing" android:label="@string/title_activity_test"/>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

The result should be a List of the contacts in the application.

At the moment the code throws no errors in the IDE, but stops at loading the application on the device. In the debugging mode it crashes at "return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);".

I saw no Nullpointers (I wouldn't bet on it^^).

Comment: You should be using a recycler view and not List view

Comment: if by any chance your test device is a **Huawei** you need to enable logcat (google it) you will find some code to dial and enable it (something like *#...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the reasons your cursor is not retrieving data is because you are missing runtime permission on your code, **you need to ask for permissions on runtime along with adding in manifest**.

something like:

```
private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST_NUMBER=1337;
private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMESSION={android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, INITIAL_PERMESSION, INITIAL_REQUEST_NUMBER);
```

for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

you need to make sure that users granted you permissions before running the cursor loader, so requesting permission on activity before running the loader is the best so that if users deny permissions (during first run) you cancel running the loader.

users can revoke permissions even if granted during first run, so good practice to check permissions are still granted each time before running your loader, if revoked you cancel the loader.

hope permission is the only issue you need to consider.